# Modular Arithmetic and Zero Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $ab \equiv 0\pmod n$ then $a \equiv 0\pmod n$ or $b \equiv 0\pmod n$, when $n$ is prime.

I know that $n\mid(ab-0) = ab$ so it obviously divides $a$ or $b$ but that's not necessarily when $n$ is prime.

Comment: If $n=6,a=3,b=4$, then $6\mid 3\cdot 4=12$, but $6$ does not divide $3$ or $4$. So it's not quite so "obvious."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is probably a dumb question but how did you make the triple equal sign? I see other mathematical symbols in other questions but I don't know how to do them.

Comment: The LaTeX command is \equiv, like so: $\equiv$.  You can right-click on any rendered math equations and then click "Show Math As -> TeX commands" to see the markup used to create any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n=p$$

$$ab \equiv 0 \pmod p \Rightarrow p \mid ab \overset{\text{ since p is a prime}}{ \Rightarrow} p \mid a \text{ or } p \mid b \Rightarrow a \equiv 0 \pmod p \text{ or } b \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

If you wouldn't know that $n$ is a prime,you cannot conclude from the relation $n \mid ab$ that $n \mid a$ or $n \mid b$.